# Generating function to word problem.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

So I've done several of these from sequences to functions and vice versa but I can seem to get this one.

> Find a generating function for the given series.
>
> The sequence $a_0 , a_1 , .... $ where $a_n $ is the number of ways to give a player n dollars using only 5 dollar red poker chips, 10 dollar blue poker chips, 25 dollar green poker chips, and 100 dollar black poker chips.

I tried using diffrent variables n it was a mess I also tried putting the numbers into the expansion but it didn't work out right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**
This is a classic that is discussed by Wilf.

If we need a generating function to give $n$ dollars using just \$5 chips, it is $$1 + x^5 + x^{10} + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-x^5}$$
and using \$10 it would be
$$1 + x^{10} + x^{20} + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-x^{10}}$$
and using both \$5 and \$10 chips it is
$$
\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{5k} \right) \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{10k} \right)
 = \frac{1}{\left(1-x^5\right)\left(1-x^{10}\right)}
$$
Can you finish the problem?

Comment: Yeah I was putting the 5,10 etc in the wrong spots would be a giant pain to solve that with all those terms with partial fractions.

Comment: @Faust7:  We weren't asked to solve it with partial fractions.  An expression like the right side of the last equation is a fine answer.

Comment: That's why I said would ^^ can't belive I was trying to put the 5s with the x term....